# Can I retrieve IMDb's movie recommendations for a given movie using IMDbPY?

Tags: python, imdb

I'm using [IMDbPY](http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/) to retrieve all kinds of data about movies. For example, if I have a movie object of "Pulp Fiction (1994)" then I can get the name of its (first) director like this:

```
>>> pulp_fiction['director'][0]['name']
    u'Quentin Tarantino'
```

Or the name of the third actor:

```
>>> pulp_fiction['cast'][2]['name']
    u'Samuel L. Jackson'
```

In ways similar to this I can retrieve all kinds of information for a given movie (budget, length, storyline, list of goofs, trivia, etc).

The piece of information I'm looking for is recommendations (other movies similar to the current movie). IMDb provides such a thing for each movie:

[image: pulp fiction recommendations]

Is it possible to access the recommendations using IMDbPY? If not, is there another way to access the recommendations which doesn't require me to parse webpages?

Comment: Pineapple Express is a terrible recommendation for someone who liked Pulp Fiction.

Comment: Nothing documented I'm afraid. You could try to reverse engineer how they do it on the website and implement that yourself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking in the source, I found something:

[http://bitbucket.org/alberanid/imdbpy/src/579c50b280f9/imdb/parser/http/**init**.py](https://bitbucket.org/alberanid/imdbpy/src/579c50b280f9/imdb/parser/http/__init__.py)

check `def get_movie_recommendations(self, movieID)`

I haven't tried it, but it looks like it might be doing what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. Don't they have any documentation? Is the only way to see IMDbPY's features looking at the source code?

Comment: It appears that there is just a bunch of README files but no official documentation. Not ideal to say the least.